# Scope of Class Variables?

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

Hello I have a module that is installed in site-packages folder. The module contains a class that mostly consists of class variables and static methods (there are no instance methods), something of the form

```
class C1:

    name = 'C1'
    todos = []
    tasks = {}

    @classmethod
    def f1(cls) -> None:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def f2(cls) -> None:
        pass
```

etc. The class variables as well as the lists and dicts are manipulated in the methods. Now I see another class (lets say `C2`) (also in site-pacakges) that uses this class `C1`. Now `C2` is used as a base class for other classes. My question is: Will these class variables in `C1` shared by all those class instances?

I an unable to understand the scoping. Can somebody please guide me to a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those values will be shared across `C1` instances, they are class attributes. You use them using the class name and then the attribute:

```
C1.name  # "C1"
```

However, you can override the value for a single instance by using `self`:

```
# Inside of a method
self.name = "A particular C1"
```

Also, when using inheritance, the class attribute will still be accessible through the subclass:

```
class Super:
    name = "Super"

class Sub(Super):
    pass

print(Super.name)  # Super
print(Sub.name)  # Super
```

Comment: So if I manipulate let's say C1.task dictionary in 1 class, all the classes that use the C1 class will have the same modified dictioanry?

Comment: Exactly, that's right